# JNI java load so and got undefined symbol Excetion

Tags: java-native-interface, shared-libraries

when I load so which compiled locally, I got the exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/admin/libLprProcessor.so: /home/admin/libLprProcessor.so: undefined symbol: _ZNKSt8__detail20_Prime_rehash_policy11_M_next_bktEm
  at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1824) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
  at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
  at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your library `/home/admin/libLprProcessor.so` is linked with another library - one that contains `_ZNKSt8__detail20_Prime_rehash_policy11_M_next_bktEm`.

You have few options here:

1. link `libLprProcessor.so` with this library such way you pass `-rpath`. This way, this additional library will be correctly pointed to from `libLprProcessor.so`
2. Add this library to location pointed by `java.library.path`
3. Before starting your Java code, make sure to export `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` such way it points to the library that is used by `libLprProcessor.so`

Answer (score 0):

**(.so)** files are shared object similar to **.dll** files in windows for loading them by JNI you need place them in **/lib** or **/usr/lib** for linux in under **system32** folder in windows.
programs read these files from specific location so you need install or put them at right place.